# Would this be correct functional and non-functional requirements?

Tags: requirements

**Hi im insure about functional and non functional requirements, are these correct ?**

FUNCTIONAL:

Player Creates account.

Player Chooses Region.

Player Chooses Player type.

Player TypeA/Player Typeb Views Game statistics.

Player TypeA Views opponent List.

Player TypeA/Player Typeb Selects Target/Assassin From Job List.

Player TypeA/Player Typeb Views opponent Map.

Player TypeA views weapons.

Player TypeA equips weapon .

Player TypeA Shoots weapon; compute hit probability.

Combat opponents player is hit; opponent eliminated Player TypeA receives points.

Player TypeA/Player Typeb sends message.

Player Typeb views target history.

**This program requires a gps connection is this a functional requirement ?**

**Non-Functional:
 ?????**

Thanks in advance

Comment: 'Requires a GPS connection' is more like a non-functional requirement.  The code isn't going to magically provide GPS.

Comment: Closely related to [Are these non-functional requirements correct?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447659/are-these-non-functional-requirements-correct), but not a direct duplicate.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not related to programming

Answer (score 0):

Urby, as written, this seems more like a Use Case.

Comment: Take a look at this, look how Joel handles a sample app - may put you on the right track, there are multiple parts so make sure you read them all, its well worth it - http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000036.html

Comment: I'm kinda pressed for time(otherwise I would), im late with my dissertation O_o. I haz no time :(, and yeah i pulled this from use cases ive made lol thought that was what functional requirements were all about

Comment: ah ok im reading sommerville(2007) I'm gathering i basicly need more description and english .....bah.