# Are these non-functional requirements correct?

Tags: requirements

Non-functional Requirements:

- User has access to the internet
- User has GPS
- Create account information has valid characters.
- Communication: Create account: user receives UserID in return from server
- Communication: Application receives GPS information from server
- Communication: Application sends GPS information to server
- Communication: Server updates requested by user user score
- Communication: Server returns available jobs requested by user
- System shows available weapons
- User eliminates target within time-lock
- System communicates player to player messages

Comment: Some of those could be considered functional requirements, depending on the project.  What application are these requirements related to?

Comment: Closely related to [Would this be correct functional and non-functional requirements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425121/would-this-be-correct-functional-and-non-functional-requirements) — but not a direct duplicate.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not related to programming

Answer (score 0):

My basic assumption here is that you are creating an application for users you have reasonable control over. i.e. you're not creating commercial software that's going to be released into the wild, so to speak.

That said, your first two items would be assumptions. You're not providing internet access or GPS service as part of your application. If you are, then these items aren't worded well.

I agree with tjameson that a number of these are functional requirements. In fact, I'd say most of the rest are functional requirements.